# Excel, create image's thumbnail with macro and sort

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with a column that contains the full path of images. I have created a column with the thumbnails of each image using the following macro:

```
Sub InsertPicFromFile()
Dim cCell As Range
For Each cCell In Selection
If cCell.Value <> "" Then
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
    Filename:=cCell.Value, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=cCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Left, Top:=cCell.Top, _
    Width:=cCell.Height, Height:=200
End If
Next cCell
End Sub
```

It works fine but I cannot sort any rows as these images are not "inside" a cell (or something like that). basically the images are not order based on the parent row.

I don't know if is possible, but is there any alternative way to creare a thumbnail in excel?

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the images, you will need to ensure each image is within their relevant cell boundary.  You can accomplish this by ensuring the image size (width/height) is equal or smaller than their holding cell.  In your code, you will need to change your last statement of your code to the below :-

```
Width:=cCell.Offset(0, 1).Width, Height:=cCell.Height
```

You can then perform sorting based on the parent rows.